# Trouble with SliderLayout finding id

Tags: java, android, android-layout, slider, navigation-drawer

I'm in trouble, I'm trying to make a SliderLayout inside of a NavigationDrawer. Yesterday it was working as good as possible, but on today's day i opened the android studio, and the slider stopped from working, i didn't change the code, and now, its throws an exception that is NullPointerException and here is what it says: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout.addSlider(com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderTypes.BaseSliderView)' on a null object reference` ;

Here is the code that im using right now:

```
public class News extends NavigationDrawer implements BaseSliderView.OnSliderClickListener, ViewPagerEx.OnPageChangeListener {

private HashMap<String,String> map;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    startUp();
}

private void startUp(){
    setContentView(R.layout.news_navigation_activity);
    onCreateDrawer();
    onSlideShowCreate();
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);

}

private void onSlideShowCreate(){
    map=new HashMap<String,String>();
    SliderLayout slide = findViewById(R.id.slider);
    map.put("Android CupCake", "http://androidblog.esy.es/images/cupcake-1.png");
    map.put("Android Donut", "http://androidblog.esy.es/images/donut-2.png");
    map.put("Android Eclair", "http://androidblog.esy.es/images/eclair-3.png");
    map.put("Android Froyo", "http://androidblog.esy.es/images/froyo-4.png");
    map.put("Android GingerBread", "http://androidblog.esy.es/images/gingerbread-5.png");
    for(String name : map.keySet()){
        TextSliderView textSliderView = new TextSliderView(News.this);
        textSliderView
                .description(name)
                .image(map.get(name))
                .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit)
                .setOnSliderClickListener(this);
        textSliderView.bundle(new Bundle());
        textSliderView.getBundle().putString("extra",name);
        try {
            slide.addSlider(textSliderView); <== Here is where the exception is throwed
        } catch(NullPointerException e){
            System.err.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

So, i don't know whats going on, but what i do know is that the `@id/slider` is from "news_content_activity.xml" and im calling the "news_nav_activity.xml" (that contains "news_content_activity.xml" layout in). So Thanks for your attention and your help.

**UPDATE 1**:
Like what the exception said my variable `slide` is `null`; But now im still without solution

Comment: why are you extending `NavigationDrawer`?

Comment: cuz the only way to use the navigation drawer its by extending from the NavigationDrawer.class.

Comment: hey @TazTazzianoTaz427 can you share the xml of `news_navigation_activity`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but what i do know is that the @id/slider is from "news_content_activity.xml" and im calling the "news_nav_activity.xml" `(that contains "news_content_activity.xml" layout in)`

if you mean in `contains` -> that you use `<include>`

Specify the ID in the `<include>`

```
   <include
    android:id="@+id/test"
    layout="@layout/news_content_activity" />
```

Then use two `findViewById` to access fields in the layout

```
View testView = findViewById(R.id.test);
SliderLayout slide = testView.findViewById(R.id.slider);
```

Comment: I'm glad that you helped, but the problem was that it wasnt finding the id, the problem was that i changed include to FrameLayout, so it stopped to work. Ty